# How to edit tar files in Unix using SED without untarring them?

Tags: sed

How to edit tar files in Unix using SED without untarring them?

I want to change the timestamp available in each of the files in .tar as well as in the filenames.

Comment: That doesn't sound possible.

Comment: any reason for not untaring, changing timestamp, and taring them back again?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are a ninja I think you'll need more than sed. For starters you need to do more than replace dates in the tar block headers, you also need to update the header checksums appropriately, header size field, and deal with all the other intricacies of the header spec.

That being said, I would suggest checking out Perl's `Archive::Tar::Stream` module, which handles all of the above for you:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Tar::Stream](http://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aTar%3a%3aStream)

Here's an example script that will update the `mtime` of all files in the tar to the current time, and change filenames, all without untarring:

```
use Archive::Tar::Stream;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
my $outfile = $ARGV[1];
open( my $infh, "<", $infile );
open( my $outfh, ">", $outfile );
my $ts = Archive::Tar::Stream->new(infh => $infh, outfh => $outfh);

while (my $header = $ts->ReadHeader()) {
        $header->{'mtime'} = time();
        $header->{'name'} = "whatever.txt";
        $ts->WriteHeader($header);
        $ts->CopyBytes($header->{size});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bsdtar](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html) command to create a new file with the contents of an existing file, using the `@` syntax. Most Linux distros ship bsdtar in a package called "libarchive", or similar. For example:

```
# Make a file foo, create an original.tar.gz file
# containing it then list its contents
$ echo hello > foo
$ tar czf original.tar.gz foo
$ tar tf original.tar.gz
foo

# We can use bsdtar's -s argument to rewrite paths, but 
# if we give it original.tar.gz as an argument we'll
# just get a tarball-in-a-tarball
$ bsdtar -s '/o/0/g' -c -z -f wrapped.tar.gz original.tar.gz
$ tar tf wrapped.tar.gz
0riginal.tar.gz

# If we instead give it '@original.tar.gz', it will use
# the contents of that archive instead (i.e. foo)
$ bsdtar -s '/o/0/g' -c -z -f unwrapped.tar.gz '@original.tar.gz'
$ tar tf unwrapped.tar.gz
f00
```

I can't tell from the man page whether it can modify timestamps (although it can exclude them, if desired)